Appying Unique Constraint on Text and Text[] column in pgsql
I am trying to avoid duplicate entries in the table based on type and names however the unique constraint not getting applied.
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('threshold_retry.threshold_details_id_seq'::regclass),
    component_type text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    component_names text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Data to be inserted:
INSERT INTO test(
    id, component_type, component_names)
    VALUES (1, 'INGESTION', '{ingestiona,atul, ingestiona, ingestionb}'),
    (2, 'INGESTION', '{test_s3_prerit, atul}'),
    (3, 'DQM', '{testmigration}'),
    (4, 'SCRIPT', '{scripta}'),
    (5, 'SCRIPT', '{testimportscript, scripta}'),
    (6, 'SCRIPT', '{Script_Python}'),
    (7, 'BUSINESS_RULES', '{s3_testH_Graph}'),
    (8, 'EXPORT', '{Export2}')
    ;

I want the result to be similar like :
component_type  component_names
INGESTION       {ingestiona,atul,ingestionb}
INGESTION       {test_s3_prerit}
DQM             {testmigration}
SCRIPT          {scripta}
SCRIPT          {testimportscript}
SCRIPT          {Script_Python}
BUSINESS_RULES  {s3_testH_Graph}
EXPORT          {Export2}

Where atul, ingestiona and scripta is getting removed.
I tried using gist but it is not working for text and text[] cobination
    ALTER TABLE threshold_retry.test
ADD CONSTRAINT exclude_duplicate_names EXCLUDE USING gist (component_type with =, component_names  with &&);

Tried creating Operator class but that too not working.
How to achieve this while insterting or updating the value?

A unique constraint is not going to reach into an array and remove values. The best it would do is flag the constraint violation and prevent the insert/update of the complete row that is causing the violation.

Don't use arrays in your datamodel, use a proper 3NF datamodel

Do you want a constraint (an error when someone inserts inappropriate data) or do you want the input sanitized?

I would suggest to manage the deduplication logic in the application layer or via a function before inserting or updating data in the table like the following
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION normalize_component_names() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    existing_names text[];
BEGIN
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT unnest(component_names)) INTO existing_names
    FROM test
    WHERE component_type = NEW.component_type;
    
    IF existing_names IS NOT NULL THEN
        NEW.component_names := array(SELECT DISTINCT unnest(array_cat(existing_names, NEW.component_names)));
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Then Create a trigger to use this function
CREATE TRIGGER normalize_names_before_insert_or_update
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION normalize_component_names();

You will insert data without checking duplicates at this point because the function will handle deduplication. After inserting the data, you should query the table to ensure that duplicates within the same component_type have been handled appropriately:
SELECT component_type, component_names FROM test;


You can do this using a function and a CHECK constraint. This is likely more efficient than a trigger.
The function checks that all values are unique: in other words after grouping by the value there is no group with more than one value.
CREATE FUNCTION is_unique(input text[])
RETURNS bool AS $$
  SELECT NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
    FROM unnest(input) AS v(value)
    GROUP BY value
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
  IMMUTABLE
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  LEAKPROOF;

Then:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('threshold_retry.threshold_details_id_seq'::regclass),
    component_type text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    component_names text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uq_names CHECK ( is_unique(component_names) )
);

db<>fiddle
If you want to enforce uniqueness of the whole array across all rows then you can use a normal UNIQUE constraint, but you first have to ensure that the array is canonical i.e. that all items are ordered. You can also do this using a function.
CREATE FUNCTION is_unique(input text[])
RETURNS bool AS $$
  SELECT NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY ordinal) AS prev
        FROM unnest(input) WITH ORDINALITY AS v(value, ordinal)
    ) a
    WHERE a.prev >= a.value
  ) AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
  IMMUTABLE
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  LEAKPROOF;

And then
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('threshold_retry.threshold_details_id_seq'::regclass),
    component_type text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    component_names text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT cq_names CHECK ( is_unique(component_names) ),
    CONSTRAINT uq_names UNIQUE (component_names)
)l

db<>fiddle

I have the impression that OP wants to avoid duplicates across all rows of the table. A check constraint cannot provide that.

Maybe. See edit, you can use a function for that also.

Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. Yes, that is safe usage. But it won't cause a constraint violation for {testimportscript, scripta} and {scripta}, will it?

@LaurenzAlbe No it won't, but then I wasn't sure that was even the intention, I thought you meant that the array as a whole should be a unique set. Yeah looks like I misunderstood OP's example.
